# How does a half-flash ADC work?

Tags: adc

Specifically:

1. Why does the first 4-bit ADC output the 4 MSBs? Say an input value of 8 corresponds to an 8-bit output of 0000.1111, where 0000 is the MSBs and 1111 the LSBs. If that same input value of 8 enters the first 4-bit ADC, that ADC has to output 1111 - and that is the LSBs of the 8-bit output, not the MSBs. What I also don't understand is that the input is supposed to be an 8-bit value (from 0 to 255) but a 4-bit ADC can process 0-15.
2. I guess the concept of the half-flash is to feedback the quantisation error into the first 4-bit ADC and per cycle I can raise the resolution by another 4 bit. First cycle 4-bit resolution (or 4 levels), second cycle 16 bit, and 64 bits on the 3rd cycle and so on. I could theoretically repeat the process and reach infinite resolution ... what is the point of having the second 4-bit ADC?

[image: z4]

Comment: It feels like the first sentence of your "2." answers the last sentence.

Comment: The first ADC would output 0000 because input 8 would not (quite) reach one LSB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a 2-digit BCD half-flash ADC with a range of 0 to 1 (actually 0 to 0.99) volts. Assume an input of 0.72 volts, and the first ADC has a range of 1 volt. The first ADC will put out the first digit of the result - in this case, 7. The internal DAC will reconstruct that to 0.7 volts. At the subtractor, the 0.7 is subtracted from the input, leaving .02 volts.

What the block diagram you show does not make clear is that either the 2nd ADC has a much smaller range than the first, or the subtractor has gain. In this case let's say that the two ADCs are identical, and the subtractor has a gain of 10. Then the second ADC will have an input of 0.2 volts, and will produce an output of 2. The result will be 72, which is correct.

Of course, for a binary system as shown, the subtractor gain will be 16.

The trick with a half-flash is that the first ADC produces a small number of bits, but the non-linearity is better than 1 lsb of the total range. That is, when the output is fed into the DAC, the output fed to the subtractor will not have an uncertainty of 1 bit at the first ADC, but rather 1 bit at the overall input.

In the case of the BCD version, the output of the DAC will step by 10 lsbs of the input range, and be accurate at that scale. If you will, the first ADC/DAC will provide values of 0, 10, 20, 30, etc.

EDIT - per a question in comment:

About the resolution and nonlinearity of the first ADC. Let's say that it is a "normal" ADC, with +/- 1/2 lsb uncertainty. Then, in the example, when the first ADC reports 7, this could mean anywhere from 0.65 to 0.75 volts. When you run this through the subtractor, the subtractor output (gain of 10) could be anywhere from .7 to -.3. This obviously isn't going to work. Instead, the first ADC must still represent 10 levels, but they must be accurate to +/- 1/2 lsb of the overall resolution. So, a 0 can be anywhere in the range of 0 to .1 +/- .01. 1 can be anywhere in the range of 0.1 to 0.2, with the limits accurate to +/- .01. And so on. I hope this helps.

Comment: Care to elaborate on the forth paragraph - specifically why the nonlinearity is better than 1 LSB and why there's 1 bit at the overall input? The second ADC should dictate the overall resolution - uncertainty of second ADC's LSB / 2

Comment: @KMC Imagine a just-good-enough 4-bit ADC (thanks to the speed and accuracy of comparators) and an essentially perfect 4-bit DAC : the errors in the ADC don't really matter as long as the DAC is accurate to 8 bits. There are also architectures allowing 1 bit of overlap (e.g. a 5 bit LSB ADC) so that even if the MSB ADC is off by 1 count, the DAC and subtractor (and some way to add +1/0/-1 to the MSBs) can repair the error.

Comment: @KMC - see edit.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast where does .7 to -0.3 come from? If the first ADC reports 7, the error (or the output of the subtractor) should be somewhere between 7-0.75 to 7-0.6 (or -0.05 to +0.05), and if there's a gain of 10, that -0.5 to +0.5 ...